# pstricks: circle and frame sizes have changed

Tags: pstricks

Feeding

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-.1,-.1)(1.1,1.1)
  \pscircle(.5,.5){.5}
  \psframe(0,0)(1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

to latex yields a circle that SLIGHTLY protrudes out of a square:

[image: output]

E.g., the lowest point of the circle is SLIGHTLY lower than lowest point of the square.  This was diffferent in 2010 or even (I think) in 2017: I think that back then, the lowest/highest/leftmost/rightmost point of the circle visually coincided with the lowest/highest/leftmost/rightmost point of the square.

Indeed, the circle radius of 0.5 units means that its diameter is 1 unit. Since the square-side length is 1 unit, we conclude that if the borders had zero widths, the old behaviour should be the case.  Since in reality, the borders do not have zero width, we still expect them to have the same width, so, the old behaviour should still be the case.

What has changed?  Is it a bug?   If yes, who is the culprit?  If not, how to get the previous behaviour back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For circles/ellipses/... `dimen=middle` and for lines `dimen=outer` is the default:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-.1,-.1)(1.1,1.1)
  \pscircle(.5,.5){.5}
  \psframe[dimen=middle](0,0)(1,1)
\end{pspicture}

\psset{dimen=middle}
\begin{pspicture}(-.1,-.1)(1.1,1.1)
  \pscircle(.5,.5){.5}
  \psframe(0,0)(1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What changed the last years: the circles or the lines? You write `\psset{dimen=middle}`, so it seems to me that the lines changed, but you didn't write that explcitly. Do we now say `\pscircle[dimen=outer]` or `\psframe[dimen=middle]` to get exactly the old sizes? And how about ellipses; have they changed, too, and, if so, how?

Comment: I cannot really remember why I preset `dimen=inner` for the circle. Maybe that I will remove it and upload a new version.

Comment: Does that mean that it was the circle that you changed in the last few years?

Comment: yes, but I cannot remember why???

Comment: I cannot possibly know this. Maybe you simply write down a comment next time you change something.

Comment: I know ... :-)  It will take some days until I am really sure to revert the change and upload  it to CTAN